How to solve error "Library is not PAGE(16384)-aligned"
I'm recompiling a native .so library for my own Android app.
I recompiled the library by adding:
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += "-Wl,-z,max-page-size=16384"

in Android.mk
APP_SUPPORT_FLEXIBLE_PAGE_SIZES := true 

in Application.mk
Then make init and make and now my App is working with Android 15 and Page size 15kb mode activated, with Android Studio Koala.
But, when launching Build AAB (signed) from Android Studio Koala, uploading the app to Google Play then downloading the app, i get the following errors:
09-03 22:26:02.654  1336  1697 E NativeLibraryHelper: Library 'libsqlc-native-driver.so' is not PAGE(16384)-aligned - will not be able to open it directly from apk.
09-03 22:26:02.654  1336  1697 W NativeHelper: Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-2]
09-03 22:26:02.654  1336  1697 D PackageInstallerSession: Marking session 1857550392 as failed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2

Do you know please how I can solve this issue ?
The .so lib seems correctly aligned (at least before build):
./libsqlc-native-driver.so: ALIGNED (2**14)
